# Get recent event based on region and eventTypeCode

Tags: python, list, boto3

I have the following json data, how do I get the recent record based on *region* and *eventTypeCode* with latest event by sorting *startTime* in python?. Need to ignore the duplicates for *eventTypeCode*. 
Is there any way I can compare this *startTime* in python, figure out which is the recent record and return ONLY that record?

**Sample data:**

```
   "ResponseMetadata": {
      "HTTPHeaders": {
         "content-length": "1478",
         "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
         "date": "Mon, 27 Jan 2020 21:24:47 GMT",
         "x-amzn-requestid": "a84471fc-8bde-4404-854e-c1656884cac5"
      },
      "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
      "RequestId": "a84471fc-8bde-4404-854e-c1656884cac5",
      "RetryAttempts": 0
   },
   "events": [
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2020-01-15 11:50:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-east-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2019-11-26 02:59:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-east-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_TRUSTEDADVISOR_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2020-01-27 12:36:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-east-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_TRUSTEDADVISOR_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2019-11-18 16:04:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-east-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_MARKETPLACE_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2019-11-11 11:30:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-east-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2020-01-10 11:55:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-west-1"
      },
      {
         "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
         "startTime": "2019-11-13 02:15:00-06:00",
         "region": "us-west-1"
      },
   ]
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
   "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
   "startTime": "2020-01-15 11:50:00-06:00",
   "region": "us-east-1"
},
{
   "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
   "startTime": "2020-01-10 11:55:00-06:00",
   "region": "us-west-1"
}
{
   "eventTypeCode": "AWS_MARKETPLACE_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
   "startTime": "2019-11-11 11:30:00-06:00",
   "region": "us-east-1"
},
{
   "eventTypeCode": "AWS_TRUSTEDADVISOR_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
   "startTime": "2019-11-18 16:04:00-06:00",
   "region": "us-east-1"
}
```

Comment: Please avoid abusing the tags: If your problem does not occur in a specific version of python then it is not necessary to use the pythonX.Y tags. And, on the other hand, your problem has nothing to do with the "requests" library. I recommend you read the description of the tags so you know when you should use it. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/info, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-2.7/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.parser import parse
import json

def events_equal(event1, event2):
    return event1["eventTypeCode"] == event2["eventTypeCode"] and event1["region"] == event2["region"]

json_data = ### Insert your json data string here ###


parsed_json_data = json.loads(json_data)
filtered_events = []

for parsed_event in parsed_json_data["events"]:
    already_present = False
    ## for every event, check if we've already added it to the filtered list
    for filtered_event_index in range(len(filtered_events)):
        if events_equal(parsed_event, filtered_events[filtered_event_index]):
            already_present = True
            ## Convert startTime strings to datetime object for comparison
            parsed_event_date = parse(parsed_event["startTime"])
            filtered_event_date = parse(filtered_events[filtered_event_index]["startTime"])
            ## Use parse if on an older version of python, otherwise
            ## strptime can handle the conversion
            ## parsed_event_date = dt.datetime.strptime(parsed_event["startTime"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
            ## filtered_event_date = dt.datetime.strptime(filtered_events[filtered_event_index]["startTime"], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
            if parsed_event_date > filtered_event_date:
                ## if parsed event date is newer, replace the one already present
                filtered_events[filtered_event_index] = parsed_event
    if not already_present:
        filtered_events.append(parsed_event)

## build the new json object
filtered_events = {"events": filtered_events}
print(json.dumps(filtered_events, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
            "startTime": "2020-01-15 11:50:00-06:00",
            "region": "us-east-1"
        },
        {
            "eventTypeCode": "AWS_TRUSTEDADVISOR_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
            "startTime": "2020-01-27 12:36:00-06:00",
            "region": "us-east-1"
        },
        {
            "eventTypeCode": "AWS_MARKETPLACE_OPERATIONAL_NOTIFICATION",
            "startTime": "2019-11-11 11:30:00-06:00",
            "region": "us-east-1"
        },
        {
            "eventTypeCode": "AWS_RDS_SECURITY_NOTIFICATION",
            "startTime": "2020-01-10 11:55:00-06:00",
            "region": "us-west-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will only work starting with python 3.7, earlier versions of strptime will only parse the UTC offset in the form of `-0600` and not `-06:00`.

Edit: I replaced the strptime calls with the dateutil parser, which will work with earlier versions of python.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AdamFeor. I am using **import boto3** in my python code to get the sample data and looks like it is not compatible for python3.7 and above

Comment: In that case, you can replace two dt.datetime.strptime calls with `parsed_event_date = parse(parsed_event["startTime"])` and `filtered_event_date = parse(filtered_events[filtered_event_index]["startTime"])` and add `from dateutil.parser import parse` at the beginning. I will edit my post to show this.